# PHP Callback - Data not being inserted into DB

Tags: php, callback, bitcoin

Ok so I have 3 files, coinbase.php, si.php (callback file), and profile.php.

Profile.php is what contains my CSS and HTML and the payment button.  It also holds the custom parameter I need.

Si.php:

```
<?
require 'db.php';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$text = print_r($data,true);
file_put_contents('coinbase.php', $text);
$id = $data['order']['id'];
$status = $data['order']['status'];
$amount = $data['order']['total_btc']['cents'];
$user = $data['order']['custom'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `invoices`(`username`, `invoice_id`, `price_in_btc`) VALUES    ('$user', '$id', '$amount')");
if($status == 'completed') {
mysql_query("UDPATE `users` SET `gigagold` = `gigagold` + '$amount' WHERE `username` =   '$user'");
}
?>
```

And coinbase.php is the file that receives the decoded JSON data from the callback when a payment is made through the button.  BUT, whenever something is in inserted into the DB all the values say NULL or are empty.

I don't see any problems with my code except I'm thinking my queries are in the wrong file?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO `invoices`(`username`, `invoice_id`, `price_in_btc`) VALUES    ('".$user."', '".$id."', '".$amount."')");` Notice I added double quotes around your variables (in this case I escaped the entire string)

Comment: I'm not positive since they are inside double quotes, but single quotes are LITERAL. Meaning `$user` is literally "$user" instead of the variable value

Comment: well from this script you dont even have a connection to the DB. More info please.. What is the output from mysql; > use the mysql_error php method : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: @Pogrindis he included his database connection via external source

Comment: PRPGFerret he has a file reference called DB.. I want to know what is happening there .. There seems to be no connection.. Look to the source. And although you said external source, nothing suggests that.

Comment: @PRPGFerret that didn't solve the issue.  IF that was the issue wouldn't my other query work?  Any ideas?

Comment: Do what Pogrindis said then, check your database connection. Also, add debug statements (echo your variables before the query) so you know there isn't an issue with bad data. Anything that simply narrows down the search

Comment: That didn't solve the issue.  Should I put my query code and everything in the profile.php or leave it in si.php?

Comment: As a side - need to change `"UDPATE \`users\`...` to `"UPDATE \`users\`...` (flip D/P in UDPATE/UPDATE).

Comment: Thanks for that but the problem is still here.